# Is there a realistically implementable algorithm for testing the termination of a given petri net?

Tags: algorithms, petri-nets

I am trying to implement this petri net simulator. Amongst it's specifications it has to return a map of reachable markings from the current state. I don't really want it to give me an OutOfMemoryError or something if I'm given a petri net with infinite reachable markings. Can this be resolved more elegantly?

In my case the net can have inputs and outputs of any natural value, as well as reset and inhibitor arcs.

Comment: Petri nets with unbounded markings and inhibitor arcs? I would say termination is an undecidable problem for those nets.

Comment: It is, and so is boundedness. So you can't decide whether any given marking is in the map, and you can't decide whether the map is finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very hard in general [(EXPSPACE-complete](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Javier-Esparza-2/publication/2371422_Decidability_and_complexity_of_Petri_net_problems_-_An_introduction/links/0912f513483451ae2f000000/Decidability-and-complexity-of-Petri-net-problems-An-introduction.pdf?origin=publication_detail)) to decide whether the set of reachable markings is finite, even for standard Place/Transition nets without any added features.

What I'd probably do is generate a list of reachable markings with an option for the user to generate more.